# Setting Telerik MVC2 Grid Column CSS Style

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

I've built a grid using the open source Telerik MVC2 grid, and one of the columns is going to be a little wide, so I was wondering about reducing the font size. I'd obviously rather use CSS and refer to a class like "small text" for the content of that column.

I can't quite see how to do this for one column using the grid. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you bind the data, Server? Ajax? etc?

Answer (score 0):

Found thid on the Telerik site:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting?theme=vista

There are two methods, RowAction and CellAction that let allow you to make changes at the respective levels.